# Have sub call the built-in 'insert rectangle' functionality?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm exploring a new idea related to my original [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917522/cropping-in-powerpoint-vba-or-other-solution-to-select-the-crop-rectangle).

In PowerPoint edit mode, it is a simple task to insert/shape/rectangle. When inserted, the rectangle is the active selection.

I know I can add a rectangle with VBA:

`myDocument.Shapes.AddShape Type:=msoShapeRectangle, Left:=50, Top:=50, Width:=150, Height:=300`

However, I want to use (or copy) the UI-friendly code that allows the user to place/size the rectangle with the mouse.

Is there a VBA hook to perform this action? Trigger the 'insert rectangle' action which then gives control to the user to insert the rectangle; then return control to the active sub?

My idea is that if I already have the original image selected before I run the macro, I can grab the image x,y,h,w; then trigger the insertion of the rectangle, and grab the rectangle x,y,h,w. Then apply math to crop the original picture.

Just not sure how to use/hook the built-in 'insert rectangle' code that uses mouse control for size and placement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the CommandBars command, you can run most controls:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ShapeRectangle")
```

To find the control names to use with CommandBars, you can download Microsoft's documentation from this GitHub page: [Office Fluent UI Command Identifiers](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers)

Some programmers also resort to using [SendKeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement), but that's a less reliable method.

Comment: John, thank you! I added the following code but it executes the second debug.print without waiting for me to draw the rectangle (it does still draw the rectangle when I click on the sheet). Is there any way to pause the macro until the shape is drawn (e.g. the opposite of DoEvents), or am I getting hitting some complex thread issue?   Apologies, not sure how to do a full reply on this site to show the code block... 

Sub testshape()
Debug.Print ActiveWindow.Selection.Parent.Top
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ShapeRectangle")
Debug.Print ActiveWindow.Selection.Parent.Top
End Sub

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please give it an upvote. Your comment has a new question, please start a new thread and post your code there.